# Timeout expired exception while reading and updating records from same table

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I am reading records from table  using below line of code

```
        public static IEnumerable<ISomething> LoadAllISomething( )
        {
                        (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (r.Read())
                            {
                                yield return (ISomething)DeserializeSomething(r.GetString(0), r.GetString(1), r.GetInt32(2));
                            }
                        }}
```

I am calling this function as

```
 var allThings = LoadAllISomething();
```

So , this function is returning IEnumerable which I am iterating using for each loop

```
    foreach (var e in allThings)
    { 
       //Do something 
       if(someCondition)
        //call function which executes below commandtext
        //Update TableName Set Coumn1='{2}' where column2='{0}'  and  column3={1}", 41, "F", "S");
        //I am getting exception at this line
       else
       //call function which executes below commandtext
        //Update TableName Set Coumn1='{2}' where column2='{0}'  and  column3={1}", 41, "F", "F");
        //I am getting exception at this line
    }
```

In this case we are iterating using lazy loading from table and updating rows from same table. I am exception as Timeout expired.
I am trying to update the same row which is currently present in loop .
Is this not allowed , if no then is there any other way to do this ?

It is working perfectly with var `allThings = LoadAllISomething().ToArray();`, but I have to implement using Lazy loading , as table contains many records and Db server gets out of memory if I load all rows in one go.

Comment: try cmd.CommandTimeout = 0 in the function which give timeout error..

Comment: for cmd.CommandTimeout = 0  it stucked for first record for long time, no luck , Does updating records are blocked untill we close reader?

Comment: can u post the whole update code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using the same connection in `LoadAllISomething` and in your loop?
May be you should close your SQL reader first to make updates. Or create another connection that will be using for updates. Also check if your database and/or connection settings are not blocking the entire table while reading.